# When to use *either* "IS" or "=" with a WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: sql

I just started learning SQL and the issue of IS and "=" has been one of my challenges when it comes to using the WHERE clause, please I need a brief explanation concerning this.

when am I to say WHERE row = 'rows'
and when am I to say WHERE row IS 'rows'

Comment: `IS NULL`.  `= anything else`.

Comment: You should not use equal sign (`=`) with `NULL` because by the specs `NULL` is not equal to ***anything***, including another `NULL`. So it needs its own syntax.

Comment: Well, most DBMSes support IS only for comparing NULLs and `where col IS 'bla'` will result in an error message.